# Is there anyway to restart an Azure classic cloud service role every interval?

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-worker-roles

I'm working with an Azure cloud service (classic) that has a couple role processes. One of them is a worker that's become a little unstable after a week so I want to restart it every few days.  Eventually the worker role will be made stable but in the meantime it would be nice to auto-restart it every few days if possible.

Is there a way to restart an Azure classic cloud service worker role every day or so?  Programmatically or via configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question on the Azure forum and on Reddit.

The first response was at the [Azure Forum,
Marcin said](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/618ebd45-0c1a-41aa-b7ea-800d3b30376e/is-there-anyway-to-restart-an-azure-classic-cloud-service-role-every-interval?forum=windowsazuredevelopment):

> You can use for this purpose Azure Automation
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/automation-manage-cloud-services
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reboot-Cloud-Service-PaaS-b337a06d

Then on [Reddit, quentech said:](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/a7523g/is_there_anyway_to_restart_an_azure_classic_cloud/?ref=share&ref_source=link)

> You can do it with a PowerShell Workflow Runbook:

```
workflow ResetRoleClassic
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$serviceName,
        [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$slot,
        [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$instanceName
    )  

    $ConnectionAssetName = "AzureClassicRunAsConnection"

    # Get the connection
    $connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionAssetName        

    # Authenticate to Azure with certificate
    Write-Verbose "Get connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName" -Verbose
    $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionAssetName
    if ($Conn -eq $null)
    {
        throw "Could not retrieve connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName. Assure that this asset exists in the Automation account."
    }

    $CertificateAssetName = $Conn.CertificateAssetName
    Write-Verbose "Getting the certificate: $CertificateAssetName" -Verbose
    $AzureCert = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name $CertificateAssetName

    if ($AzureCert -eq $null)
    {
        throw "Could not retrieve certificate asset: $CertificateAssetName. Assure that this asset exists in the Automation account."
    }

    Write-Verbose "Authenticating to Azure with certificate." -Verbose    
    Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Conn.SubscriptionName -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID -Certificate $AzureCert 

    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID

    Write-Verbose "Getting $serviceName Role." -Verbose

    $results = Get-AzureRole -ServiceName $serviceName -InstanceDetails
    Write-Output $results

    Write-Verbose "Resetting Role Instance $instanceName" -Verbose

    $results = Reset-AzureRoleInstance -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot -InstanceName $instanceName -Reboot    
    Write-Output $results
}
```

I made some minor changes to the parameters and removed the outer braces.  And thus was able to use the script as is for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely Yes, there are two ways to restart an Azure classic Cloud Service role instance via triggered programmatically per an interval.

1. Call the REST API [Reboot Role Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloudservices/rest-reboot-role-instance) with a crontab trigger in programming
2. You can restart these Virtual Machines of the role via call the REST API [Virtual Machines - Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/restart) in programming or directly use the same feature API of Azure SDK for a programming language.

Comment: +1 I posted this question to the Microsoft forum as well and someone mentioned that Automation could be used to do this.